# Difference between multi-factor ANOVA and Cox proportional hazard model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, cox-model, manova

I am wondering what is the difference between multi-factor ANOVA and Cox proportional hazard model? As I understood both of them test the significance of some independent factors on a dependent factor...

Comment: I think you pointed out the only common thing between the two methods. Thus said (sorry for being sarcastic), it is like asking "what is the difference between an elephant and a cat. As I understood, they are both animals."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level: ANOVA is a regression model that tests if the mean value of a variable varies by categorical factors. A Cox PH model is a type of survival analysis model for the hazard function, which you can think of as the probability of having a predefined event within a small window of a given time.

Both of these are often used in medical settings and 2 relevant applications would be testing the effect of a drug on blood pressure via ANOVA and modeling the time until a patient has a heart attack via Cox PH.